# How to retreive 5 highest values from a table

Tags: mysql

I have table with 10 rows with employee id and salary.
I want get a table with 5 rows in order of the highest salary.

```
create table employee(
id int not null primary key,
employeeName VarChar(20),
salary int
);
```

Thank you.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 5`

Comment: What version of MySQL? 5.x or 8.x?

Comment: @TheImpaler how to check?

Comment: What happens with ties? For example if there are two or three employees tied in fifth place? Do you want them all, or just one randomly?

Comment: `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă it didn't work ;(

Comment: @TheImpaler its 8.0.18 and i think ties should cared by making fifth place employee with name in alphabetic order.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `RANK()`, or `DENSE_RANK`, or `ROW_NUMBER()`.

For example:

```
select *
from (
  select *,
    rank() over(order by salary desc) as rk
  from employee
) x
where rk <= 5
order by rk, employeename
```

See running example (that show 6 rows since two are tied in fifth place) at [DBFidle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/932VmrLhb2sMeR9bGVm7A5/0).